# How to count the numbers where the absolute value is greater than a cutoff with COUNTIFS in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, absolute-value, sumproduct

I have the following numbers 12,34,-15,-23,-5,45,-50 and would like to find the count of numbers where the abs(x)>=15, which in this case is 5 Is this possible with the use of COUNTIFS ?

Comment: Are these in a single cell or separate cells?

Comment: COUNTIFS can take multiple conditions,  so have one for >= 15 and another for <= -15

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij separate cells. Would like to see a solution with COUNTIFS..

Comment: @chrisneilsen trying to find the absolute value, not the range.

Comment: It would be `=COUNTIFS(A2:A8,">=15")+COUNTIFS(A2:A8,"<=-15")` or `=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A8,{">=15","<=-15"}))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the inputs, following formulas can be used

`=SUMPRODUCT((ABS(A2:A8)>=15)+0)`

and COUNTIFS implementation would be as below

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A8,">=15")+COUNTIFS(A2:A8,"<=-15")`

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A8,{">=15","<=-15"}))`

As COUNTIFS requires range as input and therefore any math operation is not possible!

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. Sorry for the late reply.